# Ackerman functions structural recursion

Tags: recursive-algorithms

Suppose $ foldn : A \times (A \rightarrow A) \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A $ such that $foldn$ is structural recursion over naturals.

$foldn(c,h,m) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            c & \quad m = 0 \\
            foldn (h (c), h) \: n & \quad m = succ\: n
        \end{array}
    \right.
$

In 'The Algebra of Programming' by Richard Bird 1.6 he asks me to find some $f$ such that $foldn(succ,f)$ is equivalent to $curry \: ack$. Could I have a hint please?

Also what is the significance that non primitive recursions can be written in terms of $foldn$?

Comment: I think you might do better on https://cs.stackexchange.com for the second part of your question. As for the first part, a hint is: what are you iterating when you go from successor to addition to multiplication to exponentiation to ... (A Google search for "Ackermann foldn" will find you detailed answers.)

Comment: Thank you @RobArthan I think I will post a seperate question for the second part on CS. I'm surprised I didn't think hyperoperations would show up here but I'll take a look.